# How to implement Group By query to Laravel Lighthouse?

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

How can I make following query in lighthouse eloquent query?

`select * from mytable group by customer`

Comment: Just so you know the "lighthouse" tag is for Google Lighthouse (performance testing software) so I removed it from your questions to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no a directive for that. You can use just the [`@field`](https://lighthouse-php.com/5/api-reference/directives.html#field) directive and there you can put anything you want. Or maybe adding some scopes. I mean, think in terms of Eloquent, more than plain queries.

Comment: There are directives like whereCondition and orderBy. Why there is no directive like groupBy.. Anyway, thanks.. I think it is better to create a custom directive for grouping

Comment: Well, you can always make a PR to add it. Just propose your idea and they will take in mind for sure!

Answer (score 1):

You can either create your own directive, sth like `@groupBy` or just simply use a complex function through `@field(resolver: ...)` or `@paginate(builder: ...)` and do the grouping by using Laravel tools.